# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError not being solved after migrating to android X

Tags: java, android, firebase, androidx

Ever since I migrated my project to android x for using places api I have been facing problems ever since.I solved all the dependencies issues but now when I run the app its crashes immediately.

```
2019-07-21 11:36:33.004 11430-11430/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona, PID: 11430
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7212)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6699)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6600)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mazikeen.rcb.shop.persona-lcrbglKnfwmktutSBBFMzA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
```

here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried all the solutions over the internet but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the related dependencies have the same version. In your case, as far as i understand this should be due to a dependency version mismatch, since it is the usual case. Pay attention to dependencies starting with 'com.google...'

Anyway check [this](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/998) out, which is very much similar to your case and might even solve the issue.

Comment: unable to use constraintlayout v1.0.0

Comment: Sorry that i can not give a direct solution. just try the updated answer.